# List of SHAs that are possible for checkout in git

Tags: git, sha, git-checkout

I would like a complete list of SHAs that are available/possible to pass to the checkout operation

```
git checkout <sha-parameter-here>
```

similar to what I am getting from

```
git log --pretty=oneline
```

but a **complete** listing.

Here is a simple run through:

- checkout earlier version in master branch using

  git checkout "sha-parameter-from-log"
- make modifications and commit

  git commit -a -m 'something'
- at this point the log is "truncated" but contains most SHA of most recent commit.

  git log --pretty=oneline
- when back to master, the SHA is not listed anymore

  git checkout master

  git log --pretty=oneline
- HOWEVER, if i remember the SHA from the commit I can STILL perform

  git checkout "sha-not-in-log"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your edit. Added the git log oneline-a-like command which will show you the path of divergence on one line! :)

Comment: I thank you sincerely for you effort! I already upvoted you answer, but it really doesn't solve my problem of how to get a COMPLETE list of all possible SHA's that could be checkout'ed... The list that I get from your command depends on the currently checkedout version and typically is not complete.

Comment: if your name is Linus, please answer my question.

Comment: `git rev-list --all --remotes` should be all of them?

Answer (score 3):

The `git rev-list` should list all SHAs for all commits with some options.
`--all` will get ones locally and `--remotes` should show all the non-local commits.

`git rev-list --all --remotes`

More documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).

In addition, for your specific scenario regarding git log oneline, you can change the git log to include diverged branches using the following line:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short --all
```

I've seen this aliased around the internet as 'git hist' on occasion.